# How to change the size and transparency of data points in ggpubr::lineplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I'm trying to change the size and transparency of the jittered data points for the following line plot produced using `ggpubr::lineplot`. I didn't find any argument from the function doc to do the job.  Appreciate if anyone can help.

```
library(ggpubr)
ggline(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len", 
       add = c("mean_se", "jitter"),
       size=2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also cannot see how it could be done easily. However, we may pass those parameters manually. First we need to determine which `layer` of the plot corresponds to those jittered points. That we may do with

```
pp <- ggline(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len", 
             add = c("mean_se", "jitter"), size = 2)
idx <- which(sapply(pp$layers, function(l) "PositionJitter" %in% class(l$position)))
```

The rest is self-explanatory:

```
pp$layers[[idx]]$aes_params$alpha <- 0.2
pp$layers[[idx]]$aes_params$size <- 3
pp
```

[image]

A good thing is that this approach is easily generalizable.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this easily with the `add.params` argument:

e.g.:

```
ggline(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len", 
       add = c("mean_se", "jitter"),
       size=2, add.params = list(size = 3, alpha = 0.2))
```